# unique baggage tokken generator

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash

There are three containers, small, medium and large. Passenger comes in, check-in the luggage. The baggage should be stored in the appropriate container and generate a unique token number. Then passenger should get back the bag using the same token number.
 Trick was if small container is full store in medium if available or large. Now if the large bag comes in and there is now a empty space in small, than move the small bag back to small & store the large bag. 
How to generate the unique token number and move the baagage internally without changing the token number?

1) Lookup should be in constant time complexity and insertion in minimum complexity.
2) We can use the hash tables to store the token numbers, but token number shouldn’t get changed if you move the baggage internally and space should not get wasted in the memory if baggage is removed.

Is there any efficient way to solve this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough memory, you can just straight store an associative array:

f (token) = pair (container, coordinates in container).

Let tokens be consecutive integers, or assign the least non-present positive integer each time, or just assign large random integer (while there is an equal one already present, invoke the random generation again).

- When you get a bag, give it a token, put it in a container and assign f (token) = its container and coordinates.
- When you move a bag, update the associative array entry.
- When you give a bag back to a passenger, remove the associative array entry.

The underlying implementation of the associative array may be arbitrary (hash table, balanced search tree, etc.).